# Overlapping the dock

Tags: dock

Is there a way to overlap the dock with an application? So instead of seeing a bit off background which doesn't fit in, is the dock able to integrate with the application. So I would have full screen and the dock would be out but It doesn't show a bit of my wallpaper?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an option covering this in `Settings > Appearance > Dock`

Simply select the slider in `Auto-hide the Dock`. The Dock hides when any windows overlap with it.

[image]